# How to refresh wx.Panel correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am creating a image viewer using wxPython. I want to view multiple images individually, so I wrote a code below (partially).

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.figs = []
        self.axes = []
        self.canvases = []
        self.panelsizers = []

    def draw(self, data):
        """data is 2D numpy array"""
        fig = Figure()
        self.figs.append(fig)

        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.imshow(data, interpolation='none')
        self.axes.append(ax)

        canvas = FigureCanvas(self, wx.ID_ANY, fig)
        self.canvases.append(canvas)

        panelsizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        panelsizer.Add(canvas, 1, wx.GROW)
        self.panelsizers.append(panelsizer)

        self.SetSizer(panelsizer)
```

This works almost perfectly except a slight problem.

When I ran the code and open a image, the window looks like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCCbk.jpg)

This window consists of three wx.Panels and the center one is CanvasPanel. You can see that the size of CanvasPanel is a bit small even though proportion=1 and style=wx.GROW. Moreover, when I resize this window by dragging the corner of window, it looks like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB1R4.jpg)

The size of CanvasPanel changes correctly! Why? And how can I revise my code to fit the CanvasPanel in the viewer without resizing.

Comment: Try forcing Wx's version of 'repaint'?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already tried 'repaint' of wxPython, but it doesn't work. There are some 'repaint' methods: Fit(), Refresh(), Update(), Layout(), etc. I don't understand their differences, so I may use these methods incorrectly.